# Prove the inequality by mathematical induction

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, induction, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

If $x_i>0 , i=1,..,n$, and $\prod_i x_i=1$, then prove by induction that the $\sum x_i \ge n$.

My progress:
First step: n=1,2.
for n=1 we have x1>=1 which is true.
For n=2 we have x1*x2=1, we have to show that x1+x2>=2;
So starting from x1,x2>0 and x1*x2=1, we suppose that 0<x1<1; x2>1 than we have 0<(1-x1)(x2-1)=x2-1-x1x2+x1=(x1+x2)-1-1=(x1+x2)-2 which means that x1+x2>=2. So it is true for n=2.

Second step: suppose that it is true for all n:
x1,...,xn>0; x1*x2*..*xn=1 then x1+x2+...+xn>=n.

Third step: Show that if is true for all n+1:
If x1,..,xn,xn+1>0; x1*...*xn*xn+1=1 then x1+...+xn+xn+1>=n+1 (we have to prove this one!)

So I took a "k" : there exist a k from the set {1,2,..,n+1} and a xq<1 then suppose that xq+1>1
(1-xk)(xk+1-1)>0
then I rewrote the sequence as:
x1+x2+...+xn+xn+1=x1+x2+...+(xk+xk+1 -1 -xk*xk+1)+1+xk*xk+1 + (xk+2 + xk-1).
This is my progress please if you could give a help, because if I prove this one, it will be easily for me to prove the A.M>G.M>H.M.
THANK YOU!

Comment: [Formatting equations in LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) would make your question easier to read.

Comment: I apologize and I know, but unfortunately is my first post and I'm not familiar with LaTeX yet, sorry

Comment: If you click on that link provided to you by @ConnorHarris, you will find a tutorial for the "mathjax" version of LaTeX that we expect questioners to use on this site.

Comment: While it's hard to be clear about what you're doing/thinking, it doesn't seem like it works to me. Try doing the $n = 3$ case first, to see how the induction step could work out. In particular, as you observed, it's hard to deal with the condition of $ \prod x_i = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n = 2$, we have $x_1 + x_2 = x_1 + \frac{1}{x_1} \ge 2$ (obvious)

Assume true for $n$.
Also we can assume all $x_i$ not equal. WLOG, assume $x_n > 1, x_{n+1} < 1$

$x_1x_2\cdots (x_nx_{n+1}) = 1$

So by induction, we get $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_nx_{n+1} \ge n$
$\implies \sum\limits_1^{n+1} x_i \ge n + x_n + x_{n+1} - x_nx_{n+1} = n+1 + (x_n-1)(1 - x_{n+1})$

The last term is greater than $0$ by assumption.